What can I do about the error message "Prediction is not allowed in AAC-LC"
I have a sound file, which I believe is in MP4 format. At least
file FILENAME

shows the diagnoses
Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains:ISO Media, MP4 Base Media v1 [ISO 14496-12:2003]
When I query the file with
ffprobe -v error -show_entries 'format=duration' -of 'default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1'

I get the error message
[aac @ 0x7ff588805fc0] Prediction is not allowed in AAC-LC.
Otherwise, the file seems to play fine in i.e. Foobar2000.
Do I have to worry about the error message?
